# Uncertainty calculations.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

Can anyone please clarify what I need to do here:

$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$$

Assume that the initial velocity, acceleration and the time have been
measured, along with their respective uncertainties (see the table below). Using the rules for
propagation of uncertainties through calculations, calculate the displacement of the body at the given
time along with its uncertainty. State the uncertainty both in absolute terms and also as a percentage
(relative) uncertainty

[image]

Calculate the absolute and percentage uncertainty in the calculated displacement, s, at a time, t,
showing your calculation in full. Show the correct number of significant figures in your results. (It
is permissible to carry a greater number of figures than are significant during your calculation to
avoid loss of precision.)

Comment: Do you know how the rules of propagate of error work? You have errors in the three variables. The product $ut$ has a combined error (how do you combine errors when multiplying?); the product $\frac12 a t^2$ has another error (multiplying three things with error in them). Finally, you add them (combine errors for sum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the answer, however I will point you along the right path. First you need to know the [rules for propagation of uncertainty](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~scphys/nsta/error_propagation.pdf). I assume these should have been conveyed to you in your course but here they are anyway:

For addition/subtraction:
$$ A = B + C  $$
$$ \sigma_{A} = \sqrt{\sigma_{B}^{2} + \sigma_{C}^{2} } $$
For multiplication/division
$$ A = \frac{B \times C}{D} $$
$$ \sigma_{A} = A \sqrt{(\frac{\sigma_{B}}{B})^{2} + (\frac{\sigma_{C}}{C})^{2} + (\frac{\sigma_{D}}{D})^{2} } $$

Your equation is (it seems)
$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$ 
So you need to break this down into its different components, multiplication and addition, and calculate the errors on those to eventually get an error $\sigma_{s}$ in the end. If you struggle with this, let me know where but make sure you try it yourself first.

**Note that constants (ie the $\frac{1}{2}$) will have no error.**

Comment: For what concerns the propagation of uncertainty, I wrote a very short introduction in [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/289143/111969).

Comment: thanks so much for all your help! It's much more clearer now